# Как заменить значения текущей даты в ассоциативном массиве?

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго дня! Подскажите, может кто знает, как провести проверку на совпадения в ассоциативном массиве и заменить найденные совпадения на слово "Сегодня" или "Вчера" средствами php.
Суть в том, что делаю страницу новостей, и нужно, чтоб вместо даты были необходимые слова.

```
<?php
function get_news(){
$query = "SELECT news_id, title, anons,
IF( DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
    DATE_FORMAT(date, 'Сегодня'),
    IF( DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d'),
        DATE_FORMAT(date, 'Вчера'),
        DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d.%m.%y'))) as date_news,
DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i') as time_news, img FROM news ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT 4";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_query());

$date = date("d.m.Y");
$news = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $news[] = $row;
}
return $news;
}
?>
```

Данная задачку решил средствами MSQL, но считаю, что PHP для этого больше подходит, да и код просто громоздкий получился

```
<?php
function get_news(){
$query = "SELECT news_id, title, anons, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d.%m.%y') as date_news, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i') as time_news, img FROM news ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT 4";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_query());

$date = date("d.m.Y");
$news = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $news[] = $row;

// здесь как то надо заменить необходимые даты..
}
return $news;
}
?>
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: А зачем вам по массиву лазить дополнительно. вы когда $row прочитали у себя в цикле тут и анализирйте и меняйте. Это же всего в одном поле происходит $row['date']==...

Comment: А смысл реализовали на sql хорошо гораздо проще потом будет просто изменить запрос и дата станет датой, реализация на php попахивает кастылём.

Comment: Неужели написать if ($row['date_news'] == date("Y-m-d")) такая проблема, что такой вопрос надо задавать на СО?

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
function get_news(){
  $query = "SELECT
              news_id,
              title,
              anons,
              DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d.%m.%y') AS date_news,
              DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i') AS time_news,
              img
            FROM
              news
            ORDER BY
              news_id DESC
            LIMIT 4";
  $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_query());

  $today = date("d.m.Y");
  $yesterday = date("d.m.Y", time() - 86400);
  $news = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    if($row['date_news'] == $today) $row['date_news'] = 'Сегодня';
    if($row['date_news'] == $yesterday) $row['date_news'] = 'Вчера';
    $news[] = $row;
  }
  return $news;
}
```